# Git exclude directories with specific name except one

Tags: git, gitignore

I've seen a few questions that resemble this one and also read the [gitignore manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), but still can't figure this one out.

I want to exclude all folders named `lib` (the rules I have is `"lib/"`) except for a single folder (maybe more in the future) that is a 3rd party folder which I can't change its name, which is under `<root>/3rdparty/projectX/lib/`.

I've tried this:

```
!lib/
lib/*
!projectX/lib/
```

but this also includes other folders with lib folders that are not under root

Is it possible to add this folder as an exception? how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few options.

Full path:

```
lib/
!3rdparty/projectX/lib/
```

Wildcard match:

```
lib/
!*/projectX/lib/
```

Wildcard match with any level of subdirectories:

```
lib/
!**/projectX/lib/
```

Your gitignore was not working because it specifically ignores the `projectX` directory only in the root.

Comment: It's working for me. Remember to `git add` your gitignore file after you've finished editing it if you aren't seeing any difference.

Comment: nice, lets wait the question author give a feedback... ;)

Comment: First, thanks for answering. Second - only the third option works for me.
the lib I want to include (unignore) is under `<root>/<3 folders path>/projectX/lib`

Comment: Can you please explain in your answer why this works? or how?

Comment: The first option you would need to put the full path in, so you would need to include those 3 extra folders. For the second option, the `*` only matches one folder, so `*/projectX` will match `AnyFolderName/projectX`, but not `multiple/nested/folders/projectX`. To match any level of nested folders, use `**`.

Comment: It should be the full path relative to your .gitignore.